# What is the best practice for reading/parsing Spark generated files which saved using SaveAsTextFile?

Tags: scala, parsing, apache-spark

As you know, if you use `saveAsTextFile` on an `RDD[String, Int]`, the output looks like this:

```
(T0000036162,1747)
(T0000066859,1704)
(T0000043861,1650)
(T0000075501,1641)
(T0000071951,1638)
(T0000075623,1638)
(T0000070102,1635)
(T0000043868,1627)
(T0000094043,1626)
```

You may want to use this file in Spark again and what should be best practice for reading and parsing it? Should it be something like that or is there any elegant way for it?

```
val lines = sc.textFile("result/hebe")

case class Foo(id: String, count: Long)

val parsed = lines
      .map(l => l.stripPrefix("(").stripSuffix(")").split(","))
      .map(l => new Foo(id=l(0),count = l(1).toLong))
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you're looking for.
If you want something pretty I'd consider possibly adding an alternative constructor to Foo which takes a single string so you could have something like

```
lines.map(new Foo)
```

And Foo would look like

```
case class Foo(id: String, count: Long) {
    def apply(l: String): Foo = {
        val split = l.stripPrefix("(").stripSuffix(")").split(",")
        new Foo(l(0), l(1))
    }
}
```

If you have no requirement to output the data like that then I'd consider saving it as a sequence file.

If performance isn't an issue then its fine. I'd just say the most important thing is to just isolate the text parsing so that later you could unit test it and come back to it later and easily edit it.

Answer (score 1):

you should either save it as a Dataframe which will use the case class as a schema (that allows you to easily parse it back into Spark) or you should map out the individual components of your RDD (so you remove the brackets before saving) since it only makes the file larger:

```
yourRDD.toDF("id","count").saveAsParquetFile(path)
```

when you load in the DF, you can pass it through a schema definition to get it back into a RDD if you want

```
RDDInput = input.map(x=>(x.getAs[Long]("id"),x.getAs[Int]("count")))
```

If you prefer to store as a text file, you could consider mapping the elements without the brackets:

```
yourRDD.map(x => s"${x._1}, ${x._2}")
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way will be, you write dataframes instead of RDD directly as file.

Code that writing files -

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc) 
import sqlContext.implicits._
val df = rdd.toDF()
df.write.parquet("dir”)
```

Code that reading files -

```
val rdd = sqlContext.read.parquet(“dir”).rdd.map(row => (row.getString(0),row.getLong(1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Before making saveAsTextFile use map(x=>x.mkString(",").

rdd.map(x=>x.mkString(",").saveAsTextFile(path). Output will not have bracket.

Output of this will be:-

T0000036162,1747

T0000066859,1704